# Call php from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services, google-maps

I have an index.php which contains both JS and PHP code. The PHP code reads GPS coordinates from an iOS app and the JS reads these coordinates back to be displayed on a web app.

I am stuck on figuring out how to call the PHP every few seconds so I can get the new coordinates. I am clueless as to how to approach this and it seems like a recursion if I need to call the same file for that purpose.

what is the best way to "refresh" the php code and read the new coordinates? Here is my code:

```
<?php include_once('location.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My GeoLocation</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>


    <script>

var map;
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;  

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $current_lat ?>, <?php echo $current_long ?>);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  yourFunction();
}


function yourFunction(){

alert ("<?php echo $current_lat ?>, <?php echo $current_long ?>"); --> here I get the same coordinates 

//Will add code here to display the new lat/long once I figure out how to refresh them 

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>

$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_data = json_decode($content , true);
$lat = $post_data['lat'];
$long = $post_data['long'];

//CONNECT TO MYSQL
$con1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "location111");
if ($con1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('location111');
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!empty($lat)) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO LocationInfo (latitude, longitude) 
                VALUES ('$lat', '$long');";
  mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());
 }

$read_query = "SELECT * FROM LocationInfo;";
$results = mysql_query($read_query) or die ('Error reading from database: ' . mysql_error());
$column = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $column[] = $row;
}

$current_lat = $column[sizeof($column) - 1]['latitude'];
$current_long = $column[sizeof($column) - 1]['longitude'];


?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I have an iphone app that is calling this script with POST and using the JS to read from it. Why is that an issue?

Comment: ...Nevermind. I misread your question -- I thought you were rendering a webpage and trying to get the PHP to rerun on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking to implement AJAX.

What you would do is separate the PHP code from your Javascript, and make a page that simply outputs the coordinates.

You then call this page from your Javascript, and you'll get the result in a variable.

The easiest (but not best as you'll eventually come to realise) way to implement this is using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax("mypageurlhere", {
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("Data: " + data);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("Error loading data");
  }
});
```

Comment: should this code be part of the script above or in that separate file?

Comment: Yes, put it in the script above. You should factor your php *out* of the script above.